# css - shrink element instead of whole page

Tags: html, css, scrollbars

I have a page with 2 divs. As I decrease the height of the browser window, I want the first div to shrink (and scrollbars to appear on it), while the second div should keep it's height.

Is it possible to implement this logic with pure CSS?

```
<div class="shrinkit">
  ..many lines of text..
</div>
<div class="noscroll">
  ..many lines of text..
</div>
<style>
.shrinkit {
  background-color: blue;
}
.noscroll {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the first div `height:auto;` and to the second div, give the height you want e.g `height:200px`